# Query won't run from npgsql, but runs on postgresql pgAdmin

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a problem running a simple insert query from my C# app towards a Postrges DB.

This is the function that builds the query:

```
string push = "INSERT INTO \"Tasks\"( \"TName\", \"Desc\", \"TType\", \"DCreated\", \"DEnd\") VALUES (\'" + this.Name + "\',\'" + this.Descr + "\'," + this.Type + ",\'" + this.StartDate + "\', \'" + this.EndDate + "\');";
                GenericDbClass.ExecutePush(push);
```

And this is the string that gets passed to the DB:

```
INSERT INTO "Tasks"( "TName", "Desc", "TType", "DCreated", "DEnd") VALUES ('dddddd','dddddddddddd',3,'13.04.2015 17:00', '24.04.2015 16:42');
```

If I copy the string and run it inside pgAdmin it works right of the bat, but from here it doesn't do anything - no exceptions thrown,no errors, nothing in the logs, as if it just doesn't reach the server.

In addition here is the push method:

```
public static void ExecutePush(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(GenericDbClass.GetDbConnString());
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Edit: This is the working solution I found

```
public static void ExecutePush(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(GenericDbClass.GetDbConnString());
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand nc = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            nc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't help you with your actual problem, but I'd be careful of SQL injection in the way you build your query. Consider using a parameterized query.

Comment: I'm aware of the risk - this is just a generic exercise I have to wrap up and it won't be in actual deployment. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
```

Means "Please create a data-adaptor that uses the `INSERT` SQL passed as `sql` to do a selection". That doesn't make much sense, and then you don't do anything with it, anyway.

```
conn.CreateCommand(sql).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Seems more like what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I did a rather silly mistake, so my answer didn't suffice without the google-fu. Incidentally, it's worth reading the documentation on [System.Data's interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as Npgsql implements that, and hence knowledge of those interfaces is knowledge of Npgsql, but also applicable to other db providers too.

Comment: Well I had to get familiar with them in a rush so I kinda skipped RTFM, which as we see wasn't the best way to get things to work. I'll keep in mind the similarity between those for future references. Thank you and have a nice one.